# iOS in-app purchase items do not show up on the distribution version, was working fine with the developer certificate

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS app that the in-app purchase items not showed up on the distribution version, the in-app purchase items were showing up correctly with the developer certificate. Does anyone have a similar experience? or does anyone know what the reason of the problem might be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This usually has something to do with itunesconnect such as bundle id or in app purchase id. Make sure to check if they are correct.